# time measurement class is slowed down by a string input

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to create a simple class for time  measurements where strat() would start a measurement and end() would end it and cout the result. So far i have:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Time {
public:
    Time() {strTmp.clear();}

    void start(string str) {
        strTmp=str;
        gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
        timeTmp = tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);
    }
    void end() {
        gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
        cout << strTmp << " time: " << timeTmp - tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0) << "s" << endl;
        strTmp.clear();
    }
private:
    double timeTmp;
    string strTmp;
    timeval tim;
};

int main()
{
    Time t;
    t.start("test");
    t.end();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately there is a 1 second build in delay in the measurement.
This delay disappears without the string input.
Is there a way to avoid the delay and still have the string input?

(i use g++ with -std=c++11 -O3 to compile)

Comment: There is something else going on. Doesn't 1 second sound odd to you? I can't see how passing a simple string object takes 1 second. Are you getting the time from your output statement, or are you actually looking at a clock and observing the time it takes? If it's the former, please write a loop for 100 iterations or so. If what you say is true, it should take over a minute to loop 100 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember operator precedence:

```
    cout << strTmp << " time: " << timeTmp - tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0) << "s" << endl;
```

This is subtracting the whole seconds at the end from the sum of the start time and the number of microseconds at the end `a - b + c/d` is not the same as `a - ( b + c/d )`. As your comment to @PaulMcKenzie suggested, changing this to `tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0) - timeTmp` gives more meaningful results.

Answer (score 1):

A simple string shouldn't add that much time to a test (1 second?).

In any event, pass the string by const reference, not by value.  You are incurring an unnecessary copy when you pass by value:

```
void start(const string& str) {
```

The other option is stylistic -- what purpose does that string serve except to make your output look "fancy"?  Why not just get rid of it?  In addition, why does your class do `cout`'s?  If the goal is to encapsulate `Time`, there is no need for the cout -- let the client of the `Time` class handle the I/O.

Comment: The const reference did not change the delay. I still get 1.11038s with string and -9.53674e-07s without

Comment: See the comment I added above.  Something is not right.  Even your "fast" time looks bogus.  It is a negative number??

Comment: I accidentally subtracted the start from the end time. That is why I had a negative number. After I changed it to end time minus start time the 1 sek delay vanished too. This is really strange to me, in my understanding switching the places should only result in the change of the minus sign. However the problem is gone now.

Comment: ok it was a "small number + big number = big number without change" thing, that is why there was a 1 second result

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should pass your timer tagging string to the constructor instead of the start function. Also, you shouldn't need to do this calculation `timeTmp = tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);` while the timer is actively running. Wait until after you've registered the time that `end` is called to do unit conversion stuff like this.